# How to open a shared folder in network after authentication in java

Tags: java, authentication, shared-directory

I need to do following using Java code:
 1. win+R (run)
 2. Paste a shared folder location say: "\10.10.10.0\aaa\bbb"
 3. need to fill user id and pwd in the authentication window

I wrote following code ...

```
public void accessSharedPath(String path) {

        Authenticator.setDefault(new SharedPathAuthenticator());

        try {
            new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", path1).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

class SharedPathAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private String userName = "xxxx";
    private char[] password = { 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' };

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);

    }
}
```

Now the problem is if in my machine the authentication has been done previously then it works fine (even without the Authenticator), but when i remove the saved passord and run this it opens My Document folder.